# How can my php website handle www.mywebsite.com/customer_name requests?

Tags: php, url

You join my website. Your username is steve_jobs.

I want to have you access your content at this url: www.mywebsite.com/steve_jobs

This url would be the functional equivalent of url: www.mywebsite.com/user_page.php?user_id=4, where the user_id primary key of steve_jobs is 4.

How can I build that functionality into my php app? Is that possible?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Instead of trying to do that from scratch, grab yourself a framework like Codeigniter that is going to do that for you.

Comment: Use URL rewriting, and lookup the user names from your database to change into numeric ids in your code.

Comment: Hi Zarazthuztra. I already have a php website I've built. I'm not starting from scratch. I have to use php for this solution.

Comment: Thanks Mario. I will look into URL rewriting.

Comment: @Zarazthuztra , using a framework for just this is overkill.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia Didn't know he was trying to modify an existing site. His question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

First in your user_page.php you will need to get the username instead of user_id since you're wanting to use the username for the url, you'd create a function to retrieve the information like so: using PDO as an example.

```
function getInfo()
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * from table where user_id = :getusername")
    $sth->execute(array(':getusername' = $_GET['username'] ));
}

//this goes inside your user_page.php
if(isset($_GET['username']))
{
    //retrieve data based on the user_id 
}
```

then in htaccess you would add this code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user_page.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user_page.php?username=$1
```

allowing you to access your your user information by www.site.com/username ( Someone correct me if I'm wrong ).

Comment: Thanks Attis. I'll let you know how it works. I've never used or heard of URL rewriting, so I'm sure I'll stumble my way to the solution.

Comment: Your solution works well, Attis. Thank you. I had never heard of ".htaccess" or "url re-writing" before I asked this question, so I could not locate the post that is being described as a duplicate. This thread could then - to justify its existence - be an introduction to the existence of the technologies that handle "variable url's".

Comment: I can't. It requires a 15 reputation to accept. I tried but the system won't let me.